# Debugging .NET dll in Service called from Unit Test

Tags: asp.net, .net, debugging, dll

**The Setup**

I have a ASP.NET Web API v2 application that makes use of a .NET assembly (dll) to handle database updates (I will call it `dbSttuff.dll`). This dll is used inside one of the services that my API endpoint calls.

The method I am calling in the dll is failing for some reason and I am trying to step into the dll to see what is going on. However, I cannot seem to step into the dll.

**What I have done**

1. I have both the `dbStuff.dll` and `dbStuff.pdb` files in the bin folder of my API project.
2. I have made sure that *Enable Just My Code* is unchecked in my debug options in visual studio.

   In my past experience I should be able to step right into the `dbStuff.dll` yet when I do the application crashes. I am wondering if it has anything to do with the fact that I am calling the service that uses the `dbSTuff.dll` from a Unit Test? I am using XUnit and running "Debug Selected Test" from the Test Explorer in Visual Studio.